Closure with isolated points
Say I have a set $A=(1, 3] \cup \{4\}$. I think the closure of $A$ is $[1, 3] \cup \{4\}$, the smallest closed set containing $A$. Equivalently we can think of the closure as the union of the interior points and the limit points of $A$. But isn't this just $[1, 3]$? 4 is neither an interior point or a limit point.
Let me know what I'm missing (sorry if it's something obvious).

No, we can’t think of the closure as the interior points plus the limit points, as this example shows. (It is the union of the interior points and the boundary points… maybe that’s what you’re thinking.)

the closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ with its limit points (see here, item 2).

You are correct that the closure of $A$ is $[1,3]\cup\{4\}$ and that $4$ is neither an interior point nor a limit point of $A.$ What must then be incorrect is that the closure is equal to the union of the interior points and the limit points.
There are two similar characterizations of the closure that are correct. One is that the closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ and the limit points of $A.$ Another (that I suspect is what you may be remembering incorrectly) is that the closure of $A$ is the union of the interior of $A$ and the boundary points of $A.$ Either of these repairs this example, since $4$ is both an element of $A$ and a boundary point of $A.$
Note also that this is really the only example of this happening. The only non-limit points in the closure of $A$ are points of $A$ that are isolated in $A.$ And such a point is in the interior of $A$ if and only if it is isolated in the ambient space.
